# How do I load a dataset file that has folder name and image name but does not contain an id in python using panda?

Tags: python, pandas, preprocessor

The file I am using is a text file and is in this format (below).
The first column represents the folder name.
Here is a sample.

> 0010\0010_01_05_03_115.jpg 
>   0010\0010_01_05_03_121.jpg 
>   0010\0010_01_05_03_125.jpg

How can I load it in into my program because I get this error:

> img=image.load_img('TrainImages/'
>   +TrainImages['id'][i].astype('str')+'.png', target_size=(2, 8, 28, 1),grayscale=False)   File
>   "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2927, in
>   **getitem**
>       indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line
>   2659, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
>   "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: 'id'

I am actually trying to create a training data set by reading in a file and applying some preprocessing to it before doing the rest.

This is the code I tried and I am not sure if it is correct :

```
TrainImages=pd.read_csv('client_train_raw.txt')
train_image =[]
for i in tqdm(range(TrainImages.shape[0])):
    img=image.load_img('TrainImages/' +TrainImages['id'] 
      [i].astype('str')+'.png', target_size=(2, 8, 28, 1),grayscale=False)
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
```

Comment: I think there's quite a lot wrong here. See my answer for the first issue: you aren't telling your dataframe what `'id'` means. I think you might want to look into how to handle file paths with either [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) or [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), and you probably don't need to use a dataframe here at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told your dataframe what `'id'` means. It looks like your data file only has one column, the file path separated by `'\'`. You should be able to fix this with:

```
train_images = pd.read_csv('client_train_raw.txt', header=False, names=['id'])
```

This will label the single column in your dataframe as `'id'` and you'll stop getting *that* error. I think there are still going to be some issues with how you are handling file paths, and I'm not sure that the `[i]` in `TrainImages['id'][i].astype('str')` is doing what you think it is.

Also you probably don't need to use Pandas for this read. Since each line in your file is a path to an image, you could just use:

```
with open('client_train_raw.txt', 'r') as a_file:
    for idx, line in enumerate(a_file):
        # Each line will be a path to a data file.
        img = image.load_img('TrainImages/' + line + idx + '.png', ...)
        img = image.img_to_array(img)
```

or something, but I'm not sure what the `idx` here should be doing.

Comment: Thanks. this made me review my code and what i was trying to do